# What is the meaning of harboring cryptic in below sentence?

Tags: terminology, cell-culture

Tissue culture became more widely used at this time because of the introduction of antibiotics, which facilitated long-term cell line propagation, although many people were already warning against continuous use and the associated risk of **harboring cryptic**, or antibiotic-resistant, contaminations [Parker, 1961].

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is off-topic (english language usage rather than biology as defined in the [help]) and demonstrates a lack of the expected prior research — an internet search would have turned up relevant definitions for both of these words.

Comment: The natives are more friendly [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/298047/what-is-the-meaning-of-harboring-cryptic-in-this-sentence)

Answer (score 4):

Harbouring, using harbour as a verb and in this meaning containing/hiding (see 3rd and 4th definitions at [Harbour](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/harbour))

Cryptic = hidden/difficult to find - this is how the [word is often used in biology, particularly zoology](https://www.google.com/search?q=cryptic%20definition).

Comment: So it means containing hidden contamination.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.